# Setup CakePHP3 and Netbeans

Tags: cakephp, netbeans, cakephp-3.0

I want to setup my first cakePHP 3 project. I normally use Netbeans as my IDE. Now I want to setup the environment. The problem is, that I cant find the right paths for Netbeans to work with it.

Please see the screenshot. Does anyone have a clue whats wrong?

[image]

Comment: I'm not using netbeans anymore, but the root path should be more like `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src`, assuming the plugin (or is that native CakePHP support?) supports CakePHP 3 at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this to get CakekPHP 3 works in netbeans IDE:
https://github.com/junichi11/cakephp3-netbeans

Comment: Thanks. I'm using phpstorm now, but it seems to working well ;)